# Why is characterRange(at: .zero) == nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextposition, uitextrange

I have a `UITextView` with some text that exceeds its bounds. Thus, vertical scrolling is enabled.

Now I want to find the position of the first visible character. This is what I tried:

```
let firstCharacterPosition = characterRange(at: contentOffset)?.start
```

This works in most cases. However, when I scroll up and get close to the beginning of the text, the `characterRange(at:)` function suddenly returns `nil`.

In the beginning I thought it was only because of bouncing (when the `contentOffset.y` value shortly becomes < 0). But that's not the (only) reason.

I tried some other values and was surprised to find that

```
characterRange(at: .zero)
```

returns `nil` as well – just as text positions with a low positive `y` value.

**Why is that?**

How can I get a reliable `UITextPosition` for the first visible character?

Comment: I hope this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922331/getting-and-setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield-and-uitextview-in-swift

Comment: No, that answer is about text selection and the cursor position. It doesn't answer this question.

Comment: [This seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53940761/1032372).

Answer (score 3):

Please, try this code (remove `textView` if you are calling it inside `UITextView` subclass):

```
let firstVisibleCharacterIndex = textView.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: textView.contentOffset, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
```

Comment: That's returning the correct character _index_ as an integer value and it's probably a step in the right direction, but it's not returning a `UITextPosition` which is what I need for further calculations and it doesn't answer why `characterRange(at: .zero)` is `nil`.

Comment: I guess, `characterRange(at: .zero)` is `nil`, because there is no character in (0,0) position. It might be that there is some smallest inset, so that even the first ever character starts at (1,1), for example.
If you need `UITextPostion` and cannot modify your code to work with `Int`'s, you might try this `closestPosition(to point: CGPoint) -> UITextPosition?`